# How do I hide the tabbar programmatically on Android in React Native with React Navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using Create React Native App with Expo to build an app. I need to hide the bottom tabbar in a specific view when a TextInput is pressed. Android pushes up the tabbar by default.

I wan't to trigger the tabbar to hide because the tabbar has to be in the view when the keyboard is not shown.

```
"expo": "^31.0.2",
"react": "16.5.0",
"react-navigation": "^2.18.2"
```

I have various stacks exported as a createBottomTabNavigator.

```
const SearchStack = createStackNavigator({
  Search: SearchScreen,
  Details: DetailsScreen,
  Tag: TagScreen,
  Category: CategoryScreen,
});

SearchStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Søg',
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: Colors.themeColor,
    showLabel: true,
  },
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-search' : 'md-search'}
    />
  ),
};

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  LinksStack,
  InformationStack,
  SearchStack,
});
```

I can hide the tabbar from the navigator but I want to be able to do it in the specific view with a dynamic navigationOptions / state. If I use tabBarVisible: false in the screen component it does not work.

```
export default class SearchScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      text: '',
      showClearTextIcon: false,
    };
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
    title: 'Search',
  };

  /**
  * Lifecycle function.
  */
  componentDidMount() {
    this.load()
    this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.load)
  }
```

Do you have any ideas on how to hide the tabbar when keyboard is present on Android or with the click of a button?

Answer (score 0):

In the screen you want to hide tab bar update the navigation option. the key is enabling `animationEnabled` to true and hide the `tabBar` using the `tabBarVisible` property.

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  tabBarVisible: (navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.hideTabBar) === true,
  animationEnabled: true
)}
```

Make tabBar visible in `componentWillMount`:

```
componentWillMount() {
    const setParamsAction = NavigationActions.setParams({
      params: {hideTabBar: true}
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(setParamsAction);
}
```

And in `componentWillUnmount` hide the tabBar again:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    const setParamsAction = NavigationActions.setParams({
      params: {hideTabBar: false}
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(setParamsAction);
}
```

You can check `this.state` or `this.props` of your screen to decide when you want this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate tabBarComponent which will listen to and respond to certain events. In my case it is keyboard showing events like so:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {TabBarBottom} from react-navigation;
    import {Keyboard, Platform} from 'react-native';


    Class TabBarComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
         super();
         this.state = {
             visible: true
          }
       }

     componentDidMount() {
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
          this.keyboardEventListeners = [
            Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this.visible(false)),
            Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this.visible(true))
          ];
        }
      }
      componentWillUnmount() {
        this.keyboardEventListeners.forEach((eventListener) => eventListener.remove());
      }
      visible = visible => () => this.setState({visible});
      render() {
        if (!this.state.visible) return null
        else {return <TabBarBottom {...props}/>}
       }
    }
```

Afterwards, add this component in your tabBarComponent navigation option in your app navigator.

```
 tabBarComponent: props => <TabBarComponent />,
 tabBarPosition: 'bottom'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime setting `android:windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustPan` or `adjustResize` is not ideal idea because it effects whole application.

so that is my idea to solve that error.

#### React Navigation 5

**BottomTabBar.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Platform, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import { BottomTabBar } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const CustomBottomTabBar = props => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    let keyboardEventListeners;
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      keyboardEventListeners = [
        Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', () => setVisible(false)),
        Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', () => setVisible(true)),
      ];
    }
    return () => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        keyboardEventListeners &&
          keyboardEventListeners.forEach(eventListener => eventListener.remove());
      }
    };
  }, []);

  const render = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      return <BottomTabBar {...props} />;
    }
    if (!visible) return null;
    return <BottomTabBar {...props} />;
  };

  return render();
};

export default CustomBottomTabBar;
```

**AppNavigator.js**

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const bottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator();

<BottomNavigator
    screenOptions={bottomTabScreenOptions}
    tabBarOptions={bottomTabBarOptions}
    tabBar={props => <CustomBottomTabBar {...props} />}
>
    ......
</BottomNavigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace one line of code in android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml inside the project.This will hide TabBar whenever you open Keyboard.**

```
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        
     **Just change your windowSoftInputMode value to "adjustPan"**

    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
`
```